# Change the severity of all StyleCop rules using .editorconfig

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, stylecop, editorconfig

How can I change the severity of **all** StyleCop rules using `.editorconfig`?

Configuring individual rules works:

```
dotnet_diagnostic.SA1202.severity = error
```

However, I'm looking for a global change that affects every rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all rules for all analyzers to be set, use this:

```
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.severity = error
```

If you want just the Stylecop.Analyzers package rules to be set, use this:

```
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.category-StyleCop.CSharp.AlternativeRules.severity = error
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.category-StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules.severity = error
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.category-StyleCop.CSharp.LayoutRules.severity = error
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.category-StyleCop.CSharp.MaintainabilityRules.severity = error
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.category-StyleCop.CSharp.NamingRules.severity = error
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.category-StyleCop.CSharp.OrderingRules.severity = error
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.category-StyleCop.CSharp.ReadabilityRules.severity = error
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.category-StyleCop.CSharp.SpacingRules.severity = error
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.category-StyleCop.CSharp.SpecialRules.severity = error
```

Individual rules can then be individually overridden, like this:

```
dotnet_diagnostic.SA1400.severity = warning
```